# Magento 1.9 how to change pagination parameter p to page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Magento 1.9 how to change pagination parameter p to page. On pagination in url p is seen

```
lt/katalogas/autobuso-kebulas/autobuso-duru-sistema.html?p=2
```

I need to show like this

```
lt/katalogas/autobuso-kebulas/autobuso-duru-sistema.html?page=2
```

I googled and I have change the protected parameter to page in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager core but it didnt worked

```
protected $_pageVarName = 'page';
```

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237911/magento-how-to-change-the-pagination-url-p-1-to-page-1-in-custom-module

Comment: i checked but not worked for magento 1.9

Comment: I see that you already made the change at the Pager file. You might clear the cache or disable it and try again. You can also reindex tables if you are in your development server. There is no other changes you need to make.

Comment: let me check the cache

Comment: I checked still after reindexing data and clearing cache still it shows same p in url

Comment: Reindex the url_rewrite table then. Careful if you are at production might slow mangeto performance and if you have a really big database may browser timeout your request.

Comment: Catalog URL Rewrites(Index product and categories URL rewrites), I have rewrite this from admin panel but still its not seen